# Google app script calling menu function with arguments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google app script for spreadsheet, I created a menu item that is calling a custom function. I am trying TO pass an argument when calling the function but it seems not working.

```
/* Create menu */
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Manage PF')
        .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Create forms')
            .addItem('Generate statement', 'createForms("Statement")'))
        .addToUi();
}

/* Create forms */
function createForms(form_type) {
    let sheetForm = ss.getSheetByName('Form');
    let blankRow = [' '];
    let formName = [form_type];
  
    Logger.log(form_type);
  
    sheetForm.appendRow(blankRow);
    sheetForm.appendRow(formName);

    if (form_type == 'Statement') {
        sheetForm.appendRow(['Employee Name'])
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No arguments can be passed through custom menu items. You will have to create a stub function for every menu item, like this:

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Manage PF')
    .addSubMenu(
      ui.createMenu('Create forms')
        .addItem('Generate statement', 'createFormsStatement')
        .addItem('Generate declaration', 'createFormsDeclaration')
    )
    .addToUi();
}

function createFormsStatement() {
  createForms('Statement');
}

function createFormsDeclaration() {
  createForms('Declaration');
}
```